# Assert decorator throws

Tags: typescript, mocha.js, decorator, sinon, chai

I have created a decorator and it contains a rule to throw when it is used more than once with a class, a really basic version of it would be something like the following:

```
function someDecorator(target: any) {
    var msg = "Decorator can only be applyed once";
    if(target.annotated != undefined) throw new Error(msg);
    target.annotated = true;
}
```

So if a developer tries to use the developer more than one time it will throw:

```
@someDecorator
@someDecorator // throws
class Test {

}
```

Everything works as expected by I want to write an unit test to validate this functionality. I'm using mocha, chai and sinon.

How can I assert that someDecorator throws?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I assert that someDecorator throws?

You basically want to call it twice (`someDecorator(someDecorator(function(){})`) and [assert a throw](https://nodejs.org/api/assert.html#assert_assert_throws_block_error_message).

Answer (score 0):

Another possible way of doing it:

```
declare function __decorate(decorators, target, key?, desc?);
declare function __param(paramIndex, decorator);

describe("@named decorator \n", () => {
  it("It should throw when applayed mutiple times \n", () => {

    var useDecoratorMoreThanOnce = function() {
      __decorate([
          __param(0, named("a")),
          __param(0, named("b"))
      ], NamedTooManyTimesWarrior);
    };

    var msg = "Metadadata key named was used more than once in a parameter.";
    expect(useDecoratorMoreThanOnce).to.throw(msg);
  });
});
```